# Output purchased order Items data in Woocommerce Tracking tag script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, tracking

I am trying to add the items in the checkout for a woocommerce checkout call on the order confirmation page, but it's just outputting blank values for the items ordered.

Here's the code:

```
    <!--Onefeed Tracking -->

<?php
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
}
$items_ordered = implode(',', $items);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     var of_ssid = 'xxxx';
     var cs = '<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>';
     var oi = '<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>';
     var it = '<?php echo $order->get_item_count(); ?>';
     var pr = '<?php echo $items_ordered(); ?>';
     var nc = '';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://tracking.onefeed.co.uk/t.js"></script>
<noscript>
    <img border="0" src="https://tracking.onefeed.co.uk/ProcessProductCheckout.ashx?of_ssid=xxxx&cs=<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>&it=<?php echo $order->get_item_count() ?>&oi=<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>&nc=&pr =<?php echo $items_ordered(); ?>" />
</noscript>
<!--End Onefeed Tracking -->
```

Comment: I have Updated my answer… I get order item data, but as we don't know what is the order item data that is needed in your script, and how it needs to be formatted, you will might be need to make some changes.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what is the order item data that is needed in your script, and how it needs to be formatted…

Try the following:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou_tracking_onefeed_script', 20, 1 );
function thankyou_tracking_onefeed_script( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id )
        return;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Get Order total amount and Order transaction ID
    $transaction_id = $order->get_transaction_id();

    $order_items = array();

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product    = $item->get_product();
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

        // Set unprotected item data in an array
        $order_items[]  = json_encode($item->get_data());
    }

    $order_items = implode( ',', $order_items );

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://tracking.onefeed.co.uk/t.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         var of_ssid = 'xxxx';
         var cs = '<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>';
         var oi = '<?php echo $order_id; ?>';
         var it = '<?php echo $order->get_item_count(); ?>';
         var pr = '<?php echo $order_items; ?>';
         var nc = '';
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <img border="0" src="https://tracking.onefeed.co.uk/ProcessProductCheckout.ashx?of_ssid=xxxx&cs=<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>&it=<?php echo $order->get_item_count() ?>&oi=<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>&nc=&pr =<?php echo $order_items; ?>" />
    </noscript>
    <?php
        echo '<p>BLABLA</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and the code outputs order items data.

---

Useful thread: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks for this. I changed the code slightly as it was outputting all the order values. I just needed the items ordered so i changed the code to:         $order_items[]  = json_encode($product_id);

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but after testing this myself the code has stopped outputting the values. We're not picking up any checkout calls at all. I just need the order IDs in the 'pr' variable. Any chance you can take a look?